# Runtime Error: Assertion Failed, List Iterater not dereferencable

Tags: c++, list, pointers

Ive been trying to get this solved for quite a few hours, but I don't know how to get around this. I have a list of values in a list container like the following:

```
[0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15]
```

I have also created another list of pointers that point to every 4th element. So they point to the following:

```
[0,4,8,12]
```

I have a Method to return the end of the list of pointers. Like the following:

```
int*    end() {return *(pointerlist.end()) ;};
```

This gives me "Runtime Error: Assertion Failed, List Iterater not dereferencable"

I understand that I am recieving this error because I am attempting to reach beyond the end of the list of pointers, But I would Like the have the value of the last element in this list. I have tried doing the following as well, but it just makes things worse.

```
int*    end() {return *(pointerlist.end() - 1) ;};
```

Does anyone have any ideas how I can retrieve the last element in the list of pointers?

Comment: What do you mean "made things worse"? What happened?

Comment: When I put the -1 in, I receive around 20 errors, all looking like the following:
Error 1 error C2784: '_RanIt1::difference_type std::operator -(std::move_iterator<_RanIt> &,const std::move_iterator<_RanIt2> &)' : could not deduce template argument for 'std::move_iterator<_RanIt> &'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do it:

```
int* end() {
    assert(!pointerlist.empty());
    return pointerlist.back();
}
```

Comment: Awesome, Thanks, that Worked! Do you know how I can move forward from that pointer? For example, right now, it will return 12, but do you know how I can have it to interate forward towards the end? (The Value would be 15)

Comment: Just increment it!  `ptr = end(); ++ptr; assert(*ptr == 13);`